# Color selector for itemTextColor of navigation view

Tags: android, xml, navigationview, android-selector

I want to put a selector for the color of a text in my navigation view for itemTextColor :

navigation_view :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/bleu"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemTextColor=""
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/item_background"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

My selector :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/bleu" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/bleu" />
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/bleu" />

    </selector>
```

But I can't choose a file in res/drawable. Where put my selector? I've seen on internet in res/color/my_selector.xml but it's not working because it says me selector not allowed in an xml in res/color. And if I put my selector in res/colors.xml, I don't know how to select it from the colors.xml file.

Please tell me how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the selector directly from your app:itemBackground attribute on your NavigationView

```
app:itemBackground="@drawable/my_selector"
```

This should work just fine

Comment: Thanks but I need to put a selector for the itemTextColor attribute, not itemBackground